# I need to group multiple functions into one function

Tags: c++, function

I need to group multiple if functions into one big function with a custom name.

```
if (NPC == NPC1)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack1;
}
if (NPC == NPC2)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack2;
}
if (NPC == NPC3)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack3;
}
if (NPC == NPC4)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack4;
}
if (NPC == NPC5)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack5;
}
if (NPC == NPC6)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack6;
}
if (NPC == NPC7)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack7;
}
if (NPC == NPC8)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack8;
}
if (NPC == NPC9)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack9;
}
if (NPC == NPC10)
{
    Attack = NPCAttack10;
}
```

I want all of that to be inside a function called `AttackFunction`. How do I do that?

Comment: It all depends on what's around this code. Side note: if you find yourself writing numbered variables, chances are good that you need an `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Quentin its inside int main and those are not numbered variables, just strings

Comment: @Quentin oh, i got what u meant, my bad

Comment: It would be a long code, but you could do a pure virtual class `Attack` with the method `AttackFunction` and then do different implementations in subclasses . Then you just create the object that you actually need

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's replace all of those `if` statements with a single `switch` statement:

```
switch (NPC) {
    case NPC1:
        Attack = NPCAttack1;
        break;

    case NPC2:
        Attack = NPCAttack2;
        break;

    case NPC3:
        Attack = NPCAttack3;
        break;

    case NPC4:
        Attack = NPCAttack4;
        break;

    case NPC5:
        Attack = NPCAttack5;
        break;

    case NPC6:
        Attack = NPCAttack6;
        break;

    case NPC7:
        Attack = NPCAttack7;
        break;

    case NPC8:
        Attack = NPCAttack8;
        break;

    case NPC9:
        Attack = NPCAttack9;
        break;

    case NPC10:
        Attack = NPCAttack10;
        break;
}
```

Now we can inject this code into a function, which receive the NPC, and return the desired type of attack.

```
<attack_type> get_attack_type_from_npc(<npc_type> NPC) {
    switch (NPC) {
        case NPC1:
            return NPCAttack1;

        case NPC2:
            return NPCAttack2;

        case NPC3:
            return NPCAttack3;

        case NPC4:
            return NPCAttack4;

        case NPC5:
            return NPCAttack5;

        case NPC6:
            return NPCAttack6;

        case NPC7:
            return NPCAttack7;

        case NPC8:
            return NPCAttack8;

        case NPC9:
            return NPCAttack9;

        case NPC10:
            return NPCAttack10;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("No attack type found");
}
```

in your main:

```
int main() {
    // ... Declare Attack & NPC ... Set NPC ...
    Attack = get_attack_type_from_npc(NPC);
}
```